# Given point and distance! Find second point.

Tags: geometry

Given point $T(3,-7)$.  Find a second point $P$ such that $PT = 8\sqrt{3}$

Yes, this can produce the equation of a circle. But what if the student hasn’t yet worked with equations of circles? Is it best to just choose a random value (likely within the given distance) and then just solve for the other coordinate? Thank you!

Comment: Take (x,y) as a random coordinate satisfying the condition. Use distance formula. Essentially you drive the equation

Answer (score 2):

Very simple, put the new point horizontally to the right of $T$, so it is $(3+8\sqrt 3,-7)$.  No need for circles.

Answer (score 1):

Without circle , You have 4 simple points, one just above the given point , just below, just left and just right i.e.
(3, -7+8sqrt3) , (3, -7-8sqrt3), (3-8sqrt3,-7) ,(3+8sqrt3,-7)

Answer (score 1):

Geometric solution based on a *construction* of a segment with length $\sqrt 3.$           Enclosed are three ways of construction that students can understand without knowing the equation of circle.

To construct $8\sqrt 3,$ the length $8$ will replace $1,$ other lengths will be proportional.

[image]